# Dividing multivariable Dirac delta function by single variable delta

Tags: dirac-delta

How can I divide $\frac{\frac{1}{8}\delta (x-0,y-0) + \frac{1}{4}\delta (x-2,y-0) + \frac{3}{8}\delta(x-0, y-4) + \frac{1}{4}\delta (x-2,y-4)}{\frac{1}{2}\delta(x-0) + \frac{1}{2}\delta (x-2)}$?

Comment: How does this come up? Generally "dividing by the Dirac delta function" simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was doing a problem involving conditional probability. ^ This isnt the only way to solve the problem, but I was just curious.

Comment: I recommend pursuing other avenues because this way won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the numerator is written as: $\frac{1}{8}\delta(x)(\delta(y)+3\delta(y-4))+\frac{1}{4}\delta(x-2)(\delta(y)+\delta(y-4))$. You use $\delta(x,y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$ and simplify.

Now you can use the relation: $\frac{\delta(x)}{\delta(x)+\delta(x-2)}$ is zero for $x=2$ (because you divide by $\infty$ at this point) and 1 for $x \neq 0$ due to L'Hospital rule.

$\frac{\delta(x-2)}{\delta(x)+\delta(x-2)}$ is zero on $x=0$ and 1 elsewhere.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule? That involves taking derivatives. What's the derivative of the Dirac delta function?

Comment: Actually, delta has a derivative, but everything else doesn't make sense (and delta is not a classical function, it's a measure or a distribution). And, @jm324354, unit step function is not the derivative of delta, it's delta the derivative of the unit step function (in a sense where talking about a derivative of the unit step function makes sense)

Comment: Backwards. According to physicists the derivative of the unit step function is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: The explaination with L'Hospital rule was confusing, sorry! I meant that $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=1$.